# Sherlock: Who is John Talking About?

Tags: character, sherlock

In Reichenbach fall: John tells Sherlock that everyone gets a tabloid nickname. Then he says "Subo (or Soobo), nasty nick". I assume he's referring to some other tabloid frequenter.

Who is Subo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**SuBo** is [**Susan Boyle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Boyle):

> a Scottish singer who came to international public attention when she appeared as a contestant on the TV programme [*Britain's Got Talent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britain%27s_Got_Talent_%28series_3%29) on 11 April 2009, singing *"[I Dreamed a Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Dreamed_a_Dream)"* from [*Les Misérables*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_%28musical%29).

- **Examples:**

  - [Daily Mail - From hobo to SuBo: Susan Boyle unveils new glam look](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2056477/Susan-Boyle-From-hobo-SuBo-singer-unveils-new-glam-look-New-York.html)
  - [BBC America - ‘SuBo: The Movie’ Takes A Step Nearer Becoming A Thing](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2013/01/subo-the-movie-takes-a-step-nearer-becoming-a-thing/)
  - [Herald Sun - SuBo story set for dream run](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/entertainment/arts-books/subo-story-set-for-dream-run/story-fn7euh6j-1226510506300)

Comment: __P.S.:__ _Nasty Nick_ is [Nick Bateman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Bateman)

Comment: Is this something that all Brits would know and is just confusing to us yanks?  I had the same question about SuBo

Comment: @PaulStock - Does every American know who e.g. __JLo__ or __LiLo__ are? I guess it depends on how familiar one is with tabloids.

Comment: @Oliver_C - Ha! Very True!